# How to use edef to defines an item from a l3 sequence?

Tags: expansion, l3seq, def

I would like to defines one element from a list with \edef. I wrote the following MWE, which shows that only \def gives a result. However, as i use the result in many complex ways, \def is not an option for me.

Why doesn't it work, and how should i do ? Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \defseq } { m m }
{   \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn#1{#2}  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \getelement } { m m } { \seq_item:Nn#1{#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defseq{\listcomp}{\geq,\leq,>,<}
\edef\choixcomp{\fpeval{ randint(1,4) }}

%\def\comp{ \getelement{\listcomp}{ \choixcomp } } % Works
\edef\comp{ \getelement{\listcomp}{ \choixcomp } } % Bug
$\comp$

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you want to mix expl3 definitions with edef? commands defined with `NewDocumentCommand ` are not expandable so so do not expand in an edef

Comment: I wanted to keep latex3 in preamble, and a more user-oriented syntax in document.

Comment: `\edef` is as far from user oriented as you could imagine. Very few latex constructs will survive being used in `\edef`.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid mixing `\edef` and `expl3`.

Also, it's better to use *names* rather than commands for the sequences.

You can extract a specified item or a random one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defseq}{ m m }
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

% extract a specified item
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getseqelement}{ m m }
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

% get the sequence length, just in case
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getseqlength}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq }
 }

% extract a random item
%
% \int_rand:n { <integer expression> } returns a random
% integer from 1 to <integer expression>
% so we can use \seq_count:c { <seq name> }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getseqrandomelement}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq }
   {
    \int_rand:n { \seq_count:c { g_mathteacher_named_#1_seq } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defseq{listcomp}{\geq,\leq,>,<}

$\getseqrandomelement{listcomp}$

$\getseqrandomelement{listcomp}$

$\getseqrandomelement{listcomp}$

$\getseqrandomelement{listcomp}$

\end{document}
```

[image]